# Configuring Couchbase connection ports through their Node.js API [Docker]

Tags: node.js, api, docker, port, couchbase

I am using an official Couchbase Docker container.

Some [important ports](http://docs.couchbase.com/admin/admin/Install/install-networkPorts.html) Couchbase server uses.

Those are exposed through the container as *random* ports on the host.

Is there a way to supply those *host* ports on obtaining a Couchbase server connection? Something akin to how the server is configured [preinstall](http://docs.couchbase.com/admin/admin/Install/user-defined-ports.html) but for the client.

I am using their [latest Node.js SDK](http://docs.couchbase.com/sdk-api/couchbase-node-client-2.1.2/) but don't see a good `options` hash, e.g., in the [Cluster](http://docs.couchbase.com/sdk-api/couchbase-node-client-2.1.2/Cluster.html).

I could fall back on a 1:1 mapping (container:host) in the Docker run if all else fails.

Answer (score 1):

Docker publishes all exposed ports to a random port on the host interface if the container is started using `-P`. The port is within the range `32768` and `61000`.

Each exposed port can be mapped to an explicit port `-p hostPort:containerPort`.

This approach is independent of the client SDK.

Its recommended to start one Couchbase server on one Docker host to ensure ports are available.

Comment: Thanks, Arun. This question is about how to achieve port-mapping for the Couchbase client SDK, not configuring Docker. But, yes, as I mentioned toward the end of my post, I can (and have for now) configured Docker to a 1:1 port mapping for Couchbase, as a workaround.